# What is the best method of describing the effects of downsampling on a chromatographic signal?

Tags: python, downsampling

I am in the process of compressing a set of chromatograms to develop a preprocessing pipeline, that will end with DTW for peak alignment. During this process I have downsampled a signal from 0.4 seconds to 2 second intervals, and am looking for an appropriate similarity metric to summarise the difference between the original and downsampled signals.

EDIT: as per Max's request, I have attached the original and downsampled signals to give an idea of the general form of the signals:

[image: original and downsampled signals]

The signals are HPLC-DAD chromatograms at a single wavelength. I am looking for methods of summarising the overall variation introduced by the downsampling, or more generally methods of comparing signals of different vector length.

Comment: Hello and welcome to DSP stackechange! Please provide some additional information so that the community will be better able to answer your question. What are signal characteristics you are interested in, how does a typical signal look like, what does the signal represent?

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible metrics that come to mind.
The first step would be to upsample the downsampled signal to the original sampling rate. This would be unneccessary if you can get your hands on the LP filtered, but not yet decimated signal. From there, you could

1. Calculate the difference signal and its energy then compare it to the energy of the original signal. This would be classical SNR.
2. Calculate the normalized cross correlation between the two signals and look at the height of the peak.
3. Assess the difference signal directly regarding statistical metrics like variance or range.

Another idea for the whole process:
Given that the downsampling is done for storage memory saving purposes and depending on the actual physical process that is involved and what you are interested in, you could also think about steeply high pass filtering the signal and then just store the (complex) spectral coefficients of the upper frequency range.

If you are only interested in the transient signal characteristics, i.e. the peaks, you could do a linear prediction, threshold the error signal and just store the position of the remaining peaks. This could be sufficient for later DTW.